# Does lock need to be declared as global?

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3.x

```
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()
counter = 0

def update_counter():
    global counter

    lock.acquire()
    counter += 1
    lock.release()

# starts threads, target update_counter
```

Does lock have to be global as well? If not, how does it not cause an error as local lock isn't defined?

Thank you

Comment: Did you run into an error when trying out?

Comment: Side-note: Don't manually call `acquire` and `release`. Use a `with` statement when at all possible; it's exception safe, and avoids the possibility of forgetting to match `acquire` and `release` calls up properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question directly, the reason that `counter` needs to be declared `global` and `lock` doesn't is because you are reassigning to `counter` (with `counter += 1`) whereas you are only calling methods on `lock`. For references to a variable, if no local variable exists Python will look in enclosing scopes until it finds a match. In this case, it finds it in the global scope. For assignments to variables, Python will assume the variable is local unless explicitly declared otherwise (with `global` or `nonlocal`).

Answer (score 1):

Locks protect some resource and are generally scoped the same as the resource. In your case you are protecting a global counter so the lock must be global also. All threads that access the resource must use the same lock so it wouldn't do any good to create a private lock in the function itself - no other thread would see it.

Some applications use a single lock to protect all shared resources (course-grained locking). But you could also keep locks with the data (fine-grained locking). An example of fine grained locking is:

```
class MyCounter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.value = 0

    def increment(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.value += 1
```

Now, each instance of `MyCounter` has a lock and runs independently.

Comment: That doesn't seem pythonic

Comment: What doesn't seem pythonic? In your example, `lock` should be global just like you wrote it because the resource you are protecting is global. All code using the resource need to grab the 1 lock for it to work.

Comment: You could also declare `global lock` in the function and save an extra lookup in the local namespace if you want. But generally, if you are not rebinding a variable, you don't need the `global` keyword.